# We don't need your [approval] any more!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Someone created an [approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) tag.

The first Community tag wiki entry is only a few hours old, but there are questions months old that have it as a tag. I'm not sure how that happens without an edit....

Found this [edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6242015):

> Support for developers who have questions about the approval process of platforms like facebook application subbition, i-tunes and google play

The tag will still exist even if the edit fails.

It looks like there are about 100 questions tagged [approval]

There have been multiple meta posts on whether app store approval processes are on-topic for SO, and it is pretty much well established that these are not programming questions.

The most recent meta on this is:  [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Please vote to close questions with this tag instead of just removing it. We can clean up the tag once the off-topic questions are closed.

Comment: I'm finding that many questions are using [tag: approval] vaguely for a variety of things, e.g. a generic approve button, approving a paypal payment, an approval process in an API.  I've simply edited some of these questions to remove the tag, since it is vague and adds nothing.

Comment: So, I found an even more troubled tag: [submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submission).  Should we include that in this post or start another one?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +21/0. No answers.

Comment: Honestly, a tag for approval might be useful. But a more specific one, might be better. Such a some approval tag for paypal, and a different one for a different API.

As each approval process are likely going to be very different from another.

Comment: @needoriginalname, please do post an answer asking for a disambiguation. That would help us see what the community feels about it.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +53/0. A1 (Saying yes): +36/0. The community has unanimously voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: TBH, I've never seen a burnination where there has been no downvotes, and I do have a bit of experience with burns .. :o

Answer (score 40):

I agree with the burnination. "approval" is not worthy of being a separate tag. I checked all the 89 questions in the tag, it is being used for different kinds of approvals like, admin approval, salesforce approval process, Facebook App approvals and so on. Also, 10% of the questions in the tag are already closed, and less than 20% of the questions have a positive score. Answering the 4 questions:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  No and no. Approval does not describe the contents in any way. Also, we don't know what kind of approval they are speaking about, which makes it completely ambiguous.
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Approval as such doesn't make much sense, and is therefore not on topic for the site.
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  No, as already mentioned, it does not add any kind of additional information other than what is already there. It is clearly a dependent tag.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Unless we know what kind of approval, it does not mean the same in all common contexts as well. For us to know what kind of approval, it needs another tag.

Another factor that points at burninating tag is the fact that there's not even 1 user who has answered more than 1 post with that tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/approval/topusers.

Comment: Scorched earth policy?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: The last bit seems like the best argument . If a tag doesn't attract particular individuals to a question based on interest or knowledge, what good is it?

Answer (score 6):

[approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=approval),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapproval%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapproval%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapproval%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapproval%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188857)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=276924)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) tag —just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approval) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Wow that's a really nice dashboard!